# Problems with extracting a row from a matrix

Tags: matrix, output

I have a 4 times 4 matrix which has very "large" entries (it takes almost ten minutes to initialize it).
Supposing its name its `M`, I'd like Mathematica to write the first row, so I wrote

```
M[[1]]
```

but it seems it cannot write it (evaluation continues to go on, but without any results). Is there a way to solve this problem? Maybe by choosing a different output form or something like this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "write it". Printing does certainly make no sense with very large data. You can save it for later processing. Or you can write it to a file.

Comment: I'd like to have it "readable", so, for example a binary file is not what I need, but is it more efficient to write on a .txt file?

Comment: What are you storing in the matrix? I assume it's not numbers, or it wouldn't take that long. If it's complex symbolic expressions, it might not be very readable even in text form, but you can use [`Put`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) to write it out to a file, and [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html) to load it back in.